# Minipage size management

Tags: minipage

I want my electrical circuit to be next to a text: for that, I use the environment `minipage`

Except that with this, I get a warning for `overfull \hbox`.

Is there a method to correctly set the size of my minipage (or another environment that would allow me to achieve this more easily) ?
thanks

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[european, straightvoltages, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
 
 \begin{circuitikz}
 \draw (0,0) 
  to [vsource, l=\SI{6}{V}] (0,3)
  to[lamp, l=\mbox{\SI{6}{\volt}, \SI{100}{mA}}] (3,3)
  to [lamp, l2=\SI{6}{\volt} and \SI{100}{mA}, l2 halign=c] (3,0)
  to[R, l=\SI{10}{\ohm}] (0,0)
  ;
 \end{circuitikz}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.55\textwidth}          \vspace{0pt}
\textbf{Manipulation}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Faire le montage ;
    \item Mesurer, pour chaque dipôle, la tension à ses bornes.
        \end{itemize}
\end{minipage} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the tikz picture is already a box so you don't really need the minipage wrapper in that case, then you don't need to guess its width. You can adjust the vertical aligment with `\raisebox`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[european, straightvoltages, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}
 
\raisebox{\dimexpr\baselineskip-\height}{%
 \begin{circuitikz}
 \draw (0,0) 
  to [vsource, l=\SI{6}{V}] (0,3)
  to[lamp, l=\mbox{\SI{6}{\volt}, \SI{100}{mA}}] (3,3)
  to [lamp, l2=\SI{6}{\volt} and \SI{100}{mA}, l2 halign=c] (3,0)
  to[R, l=\SI{10}{\ohm}] (0,0)
  ;
 \end{circuitikz}}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\textwidth}
\textbf{Manipulation}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Faire le montage ;
    \item Mesurer, pour chaque dipôle, la tension à ses bornes.
        \end{itemize}
\end{minipage} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain to me a little more what the line `\raisebox{\dimexpr\baselineskip-\height}` does

Comment: @Nicolas if you do not use raisebox then the baseline of your heading in the minipage would be the bottom of the picture, if you use `\raisebox{-\height}{...}` then the circuit is lowered so teh baseline of the heading would be aligned with the top of the picture, but that looks too high, so this lowers the circuit by its full height minus a baselineskip so the heading baseline aligns a baseline below the top of the circuit. try the example with those raisebox settings, you'll see

Comment: thanks. To center the text in front of the circuit, is raisebox suitable?

Comment: @Nicolas vertcally center? raise it by .5\height  (perhaps not exactly .5 depending what looks best)