# Vertically center a minipage next to another box

Tags: minipage

Hello,

In the rest of my previous request ([Minipage size management](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586878/minipage-size-management/586880?noredirect=1#comment1474754_586880), I would like the text next to my circuit to be centered vertically in relation to the circuit.

I tested as suggested the raisebox command but being done, the text is found under the circuit and not next to it.

What do I need to change to get there?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[european, straightvoltages, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}
 
\raisebox{\dimexpr\baselineskip-\height}{%
 \begin{circuitikz}
 \draw (0,0) 
  to [vsource, l=\SI{6}{V}] (0,3)
  to[lamp, l=\mbox{\SI{6}{\volt}, \SI{100}{mA}}] (3,3)
  to [lamp, l2=\SI{6}{\volt} and \SI{100}{mA}, l2 halign=c] (3,0)
  to[R, l=\SI{10}{\ohm}] (0,0)
  ;
 \end{circuitikz}}\hfill
 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\textwidth}
\raisebox{\dimexpr\baselineskip-\height}{%
\textbf{Manipulation}}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Faire le montage ;
    \item Mesurer, pour chaque dipôle, la tension à ses bornes.
        \end{itemize}
\end{minipage} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: because of the blank line after  `\end{circuitikz}}\hfill` -- put a comment `%` in the blank line and try

Comment: you have vertically centred the circuit, the minipage would have been vertically centred by default but it is top aligned because of the `[t]` (which I think I added:-) just delete that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use two mini pages and add `baseline` option to `circuitikz` code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[european, straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}\centering % <---
    \begin{circuitikz}[baseline] % <---
\draw (0,0) to [vsource=\SI{6}{V}]                       (0,3)
            to [lamp={\SI{6}{\volt}, \SI{100}{mA}}] (3,3)
            to [lamp, l2=\SI{6}{\volt} and \SI{100}{\milli\ampere},
                      l2 halign=c]                  (3,0)
            to [R=\SI{10}{\ohm}]                    (0,0)
            ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\textbf{Manipulation}
    \begin{itemize}
\item Faire le montage ;
\item Mesurer, pour chaque dipôle, la tension à ses bornes.
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Off-topic:
You may consider to employ `enumitem` package and than write your list as:

```
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
\item Faire le montage ;
\item Mesurer, pour chaque dipôle, la tension à ses bornes.
    \end{itemize}
```

[image]

or

```
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, label=\textbullet]
\item Faire le montage ;
\item Mesurer, pour chaque dipôle, la tension à ses bornes.
    \end{itemize}
```

[image]

Comment: When I compile the code, I get a warning because of an `overfull hbox` (thanks for the tip for enumitem)

Comment: @Nicolas, you are right. This is due to missed `\noindent` before first `minipage`. Corrected now!

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly

Comment: @Nicolas, if you insert both mini pages into `figure` float or in `center`  environment, than you not need `noident` before the first `minipage`.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
%\usepackage[french]{babel}
%\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[european, straightvoltages, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}
    
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\baselineskip-0.7\height}{%
        \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw (0,0) 
            to [vsource, l=\SI{6}{V}] (0,3)
            to[lamp, l=\mbox{\SI{6}{\volt}, \SI{100}{mA}}] (3,3)
            to [lamp, l2=\SI{6}{\volt} and \SI{100}{mA}, l2 halign=c] (3,0)
            to[R, l=\SI{10}{\ohm}] (0,0)
            ;
    \end{circuitikz}}\hspace{2cm}
%   
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\textwidth}
%       \raisebox{\dimexpr\baselineskip-0.5\height}{%
            \textbf{Manipulation}
%       }
        
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Faire le montage ;
            \item Mesurer, pour chaque dipôle, la tension à ses bornes.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage} 
    
\end{document}
```